# trying to sort a user input list

Tags: python, loops, sorting

Im new at python.  Im creating a script that allows a user to input three names and then the code should print the names and then print them sorted (alphabetically).  I can get the code to return the sorted individual letters, but not the full names as strings.  I really want to run AS A LOOP!!!here is what i have so far

```
print ('Enter three names, when done hit enter with a blank: ')

a = (raw_input('enter first name: ')) 
b = (raw_input('enter first name: '))
c = (raw_input('enter first name: ')) 

while not raw_input == "":
    print a + b + c
    break

srtd = a + b + c
name = srtd

for name in sorted(srtd):
    print name
```

Comment: ... what's the point of having a `while` and `break`ing out just after it? Also `raw_input` is a function which will never be `== ""` so that weird code is equivalent to just `print a+b+c`. If you want to print the inputs sorted you want to put them into a list, not concatenate them: `for name in sorted([a,b,c]): print name`.

Answer (score 0):

```
print "Enter three names\n"
a = raw_input("Enter first name: ")
b = raw_input("Enter second name: ")
c = raw_input("Enter third name: ")
names = [a, b, c]
print a, b, c
for name in sorted(names):
    print name
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a list in python it has a good function called sort you can call it from list code

```
print ('Enter three names, when done hit enter with a blank: ')

a = (raw_input('enter first name: ')) 
b = (raw_input('enter first name: '))
c = (raw_input('enter first name: ')) 

my_list = [a,b,c]
my_list.sort()
print my_list
```

if you want to print without the brackets use loop hope this helpful